# SF TV movie or mini-series, human boy and various aliens fight against alien conqueror

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

As a kid in the eighties I saw (part of) a TV movie or mini-series that I'm trying to track down. It was live-action in English.

A human boy somehow ends up as one of the pilots on a selection of various space-fighters. The other pilots/crew are members of various alien species. The ships are all different too.
They are the last free people fighting an alien conqueror.

The alien bad guy has the charming habit to chop body parts of the various people he has killed and use them as replacement parts for his own body. He is basically a random collections of mismatched body parts at this point.

Among the good guys there is a female pilot from a very warlike and aggressive race (she is possibly the last survivor of her people). She has a very large chip on her shoulder and considers herself the ultimate warrior. I think she was a Valkyrie or some similar name and wore a winged helmet.

Another of the good guys is a group of 6 or 7 white skinned aliens that have a collective mind and telepathic powers.

Very notable scene (and the only one I really remember well): One of the white guys from the hive mind gets killed and one of his arms is used as a replacement by the bad guy. The others of the group combine their psi-powers to remote control the arm and they try to strangle the bad guy with the arm.
I can't recall if they succeeded or not.

EDIT: The Last Starfighter isn't it. I should have mentioned that straight away. Even though it also has a severed arm strangling someone it is NOT the movie I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kids story, probably late 80's/early 90's: boy plays arcade game that is actually a test by aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79243/kids-story-probably-late-80s-early-90s-boy-plays-arcade-game-that-is-actuall)

Comment: @jeffronicus The answer there is a book not a live action show/film. Also please don't vote/flag to close a story id question as a duplicate unless both questions have a confirmed answer that is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Battle Beyond the Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Stars) from 1980.

The hive mind is a group of clones, named Nestor.  As you remember, one of the clones is captured and the main villain had one of the clones arms grafted onto him to replace a missing one of his own.  That arm is controlled by the rest of the clones during the big spaceship fight at the  climax of the film.

There is a Valkeriye named Saint Exmin, she pilots a small but we'll armed fighter.  The main character, Shad (played by Richard Thomas) finds her along with 6 other fighters/mercenaries to fight on behalf of the planet Amir against the warlord Sador (played by John Saxon).

I'll edit more information in later when not on mobile.

Comment: That is it. Nestor and St. Exmin. Now you mention them I do recognize those names.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [The Last Starfighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter) due to a young human boy being recruited into an alien war due to his success with a video game, though not all the remembered details match. Later:

> Alex discovers Beta and contacts Centauri to retrieve him. Centauri
> arrives just as Alex and Beta are attacked by an alien assassin, a
> Zando-Zan, in Xur's service; Centauri shoots off its right arm. He
> then explains that more Zando-Zan will be coming and the only way for
> Alex to protect his family (and Earth) is to embrace his ability as a
> Starfighter. **Before Alex can reply, the assassin (mentally controlling
> its severed arm) attempts to shoot Alex.** Centauri jumps in the way,
> taking the hit and killing the alien.

Comment: I've seen the Last Starfighter and it isn't the same movie. Should have mentioned that in the question itself. Will edit that in.